# iPhone OS 4 Multitasking - Playing Audio In background

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use iPhone OS 4.0's multitasking capability. I tried to play audio in the background with no luck. I added UIBackgroundModes property in info.plist and mentioned requires audio to play in background. Also I added the code for playing the audio. 
`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someday" ofType:@"mp3"]]; 
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[audioPlayer play];
```

`. The audio starts playing once i click on button in the app. But when I shut the app it stops. How can I make it play in the background?

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: You might find that people won't want to answer this question until the NDA covering iOS4 is lifted...

Comment: Yeah, take it to the official forums.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161635/entering-background-on-ios4-to-play-audio

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't set up your Audio Session correctly.  From http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html :

For example, when using the default audio session, audio in your application stops when the Auto-Lock period times out and the screen locks. If you want to ensure that playback continues with the screen locked, include the following lines in your application’s initialization code:

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

The AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback category ensures that playback continues when the screen locks.
Activating the audio session puts the specified category into effect.

Answer (score 2):

HI,

I think this video helps u in solving ur problem...
IN WWDC videos they have clearly explained how u can enable the back ground audio...
http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/
to view or download these videos u need to have a apple account...
and in that see Session 109-Adopting multitasking on iPhone OS, Part2...
Hope this will help u..

~Raviraja