# iOS4 and audio playback during backgrounding

Tags: iphone

When my app is backgrounded, the audioplayer continues to play, but i cant hear any sound. When i open my app again, it plays from the point where it would have been had the app not been backgrounded at all. This shows that the app is playing in the background though it is not audible. Why could this be happening?

I have set the audio key in the info.plist for the UIBackgroundModes array. Also my audioplayer is set to the "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback" category with an override to allow for audio mixing. So what am i doing wrong that im unable to hear the audio even though it is playing in the background?

Could this be an issue with the simulator alone as i have not been able to test this on a device with iOS4 so iv only been testing it on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the simulator most likely.  I implemented what you stated and it works just fine on the device:  [Entering background on iOS4 to play audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161635/entering-background-on-ios4-to-play-audio)