# iphone sdk: Is it possible to play audio playlist in the background in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, audio, background, ios4, avaudioplayer

I tried to implement this. My original post is here

[iphone: playing audio playlist in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297571/iphone-playing-audio-playlist-in-the-background)

So after some testing I begin to doubt whether it's even possible.
does anyone know whether it's possible to use AVAudioPlayer to play multiple tracks in the background? I myself haven't found apps that have this.
What I have found are apps like pandora, that stream audio (and probably use one call to AVAudioPlayer)

---

THE SOLUTION

Just add [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]; and some other tweaks. It's all here 
https://devforums.apple.com/message/264397

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THE SOLUTION

Just add [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]; and some other tweaks. It's all here 
https://devforums.apple.com/message/264397