# AVPlayer play video in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using AVPlayer to play a video in my app,now i want to let the video play in background mode.

this is what i put in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];    
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

and i also add to the plist:
Required background modes -> App plays audio

I add this too:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    switch (event.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            NSLog(@"4");
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            NSLog(@"3");
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            NSLog(@"2");
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            NSLog(@"1");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And when i move the app to the background and press the buttons the nslog print to the console

Did i need to add something else?

Comment: Follow this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771105/how-do-i-get-my-avplayer-to-play-while-app-is-in-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];` and some other tweaks. It's all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3330913/932011).

Comment: Wait. This worked? Video works in the background? From all the noise on the internet I thought background video was impossible on iOS! @MTA, Please confirm if possible.

Comment: @dev I can confirm that it works. You need to lock your device and not press the home button. You can also support home button registering for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and with a timer restart the video, you get a little lag (faded) but it is better than nothing.

Comment: I've answered to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15523272/616964) question with complete details on how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: link to explanation is broken