# How to play music in background iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working on an app,i have  set timer in app, after that i went in background and when time is over i want to play music in background.but music is not play?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297571/iphone-playing-audio-playlist-in-the-background check this thread

Answer (score 3):

refer a [ios-sdk_background-audio](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/). You'll be very helpful. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

Use this Timer Code for set the Timer

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask =0;
UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
}];

 self.secondsTimer = [NSTimer 
                         scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                         target:self 
                         selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) 
                         userInfo:nil 
                         repeats:NO];
```

fire Method-`- (void) timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *) theTimer
{}`

In This fire Method use Below Code for Playing media file-

`NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"tujhbinjena"
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];`

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];`

```
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
               initWithContentsOfURL:url
               error:&error];
audioPlayer.delegate=self;
audioPlayer.volume=1.0;
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", 
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play]
}`
```

> [self becomeFirstResponder];
>       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
>       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

and in **ViewDidUnload** you need to do these following lines

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self resignFirstResponder];
```

you need to handle the **AVAudioPlayerDelegate** delegate methods as per and for playing audio in background you need to add one Parameter in **Info.plist** That is "**Required background modes**" and value for this key is "**App plays audio**". Please let me know if any doubt.

Comment: i have tried all things but its not working music is not play in background,if you have any demo code please give me.

Comment: Did you change the file name??

Comment: Yes,i have change all things but not working ,its working fine .but when i went in background music stop...........

Comment: Hey, i have added few more lines of code, i have tasted in my sample it is working.So add these updated lines and let me know .

Comment: okey ,your code is working fine, but my requirement is different.my requirement is.i have set music in my app with timer,now timer is running,and i went in background,after time completetion ,i want to play music but its not play.

Comment: Check whether timer is working or not while you are in the background,If you found my ans working you can make it up.Thanks

Comment: Check i have added the few line before creating timer.Use that and let me know.

Comment: Nope,Everything i have done here.The previous one is working or not for you? cannot comment more due to limit.you need to explore the rest of the thing.

Comment: Check this [Link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/)

Comment: Hey Mani, if it's working you can vote and accept it.That would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

for this function you can use this method:--

```
 -(void)notificationSchedue

   {

  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
```

//---------remainingTime NSUserDefaults  contain the future date--------//

```
   NSString *datevalueremaining= [[NSUserDefaults   standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"remainingTime"];


   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

   NSDate *dateremaining=[dateFormat dateFromString:datevalueremaining];


   NSDate *pickerDate = dateremaining;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                                fromDate:pickerDate];

// Set up the fire time
 NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

  [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];

  [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];

  [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
  [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];

  [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
   NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
   [dateComps release];

  if (localNotif)
  { 
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotif];
     [localNotif release];
   }
  localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  if (localNotif == nil)
    return;

  localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;

  localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


  localNotif.alertBody = @"Your Time is Over";

  localNotif.alertAction = @"View";



 NSString *stringvalue=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"goodNight"];
```

//-----music should be less then or equal to 30 sec---//

```
   localNotif.soundName=@"s1.mp3";

    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];

 localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

 }
```

Comment: But using this code the alarm will be played just for 30sec. what if I want it to play continously