# Is it possible to play video continuiusly after go to other view and come back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video on the first view that use 'MPMoviePlayerController'. I declare the video in 'viewDidLoad' method. I need the video play continuously when go to another view and come back. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

yes it Possibe play video in background mode try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297571/iphone-playing-audio-playlist-in-the-background/3330913#3330913)

Hope it Help You