# background audio using multitasking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to play audio continuously using multitasking even when user has pressed home button??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entering background on iOS4 to play audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161635/entering-background-on-ios4-to-play-audio)

Answer (score 0):

With new iOS 4 there are 3 default methods for use multitasking and play audio is one of them!
To do this follow this steps:
1. Open you application's **Info.plist** file.
2. Add a new row and type in the **Key** field "**Required background modes**".
3. Expand this array and for **Item 0**, type in the **Value** field "**App plays audio**"
That's all!

Finally I advise you to implement all the multitasking methods in the App Delegate for a best user experience :)

Comment: I tried this But it didnt worked out in my case..can you help me with someother solution ..