# Force other apps to release microphone in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, background

I noticed it is possible for an iOS app to continue recording audio in the background while another app is in the foreground recording audio (note that this [isn't strait forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161635/entering-background-on-ios4-to-play-audio/3161899#3161899) on the iOS simulator, but a [hack involving a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161899/5377) makes it possible).

**Is there any way to ensure that no other apps are recording audio before you start to record?**  If so, is there any way to stop other recording apps so that an app can record?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284402/how-to-disable-ios-system-sounds), as although it is not exactly what you wanted, I'm sure it can be modified to work with AVAudioRecorder too. What this will do, is stop certain sounds from occurring (of course, if you modify it then it would stop recording) when your app loads. You could implement this in your viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot hinder another applications functions (well not using the iOS SDK) the only way this would be possible is on a jailbroken iPhone. But with an application built for the App Store this is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may just tell user you can not get access, let them to turn off other background app.