# Xcode UIWebview background audio

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a simple iPhone App that uses UIWebView to show a mobile site that I have that allows users to create a playlist and listen to it online. Since I am not familiar with IOS development I thought that if I created an app with UIWebview and embedding my site on there it would work. And it does work perfectly, but when the app is in background mode, it stops playing the music.

How can I make it keep playing in background mode, even when iphone is locked. Also to make it play when iPhone is muted. I have found other topics on this but I have never created an app before and I am just working on this one simple UIWebview app.

If some one can please tell me exactly on what file I need to add the code and in what part of the file.

Please not that in the App Info I already enables the audio in background for the background modes. But it still does not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please this below links. I think this will help you..

1. [Continue playing audio from html5 player when in iOS background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783220/continue-playing-audio-from-html5-player-when-in-ios-background-mode)
2. [UIWebView: HTML5 audio pauses in iOS 6 when app enters background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background)
3. http://www.dforge.net/2013/02/18/uiwebview-muted-sound-in-ios6/