# html5 audio background ios not playing

Tags: ios, html, background

I have checked multiple threads in SO and on google as well, but I didn't find any working model so far. So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I built a html5 based music player app for android and after the song is selected, the song continues to play in background. I am building a similar version for iOS using Cordova CLI/Xcode as well, but I found that the moment I click on Home button, the audio stops playing.

Like I said, I have looked into multiple places, but I didn't  quite find any good step by steps to get the process working. Any proper guide with help would be greaaaaatly appreciated!! I did try adding in info.plist UIBackground string with audio play, but it is not working for me. So, looks like there are multiple things that need to be done.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783220/continue-playing-audio-from-html5-player-when-in-ios-background-mode?rq=1

Comment: I did look at that, but it's not pointing precisely where the code needs to be done.