# UIWebview will not play in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview which play video from the web .
I would like it to work in background,so you hear the audio .
I have set the background mode in `info` to play `audio and airplay` .
I have set the session with :

```
 //allow music app delegate
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
```

I have read :
[Continue playing audio from html5 player when in iOS background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783220/continue-playing-audio-from-html5-player-when-in-ios-background-mode)

and i read
 [UIWebView: HTML5 audio pauses in iOS 6 when app enters background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background)

Which offers the same thing . But still , when i go to background, it stops playing the video/ audio.(iPhone 4, iOS7,Xcode 6 ).

Is there something else i can do ?

thank you .

Comment: seems there is no solution and that iOS is stoping all activities inside the web view. the only solution i found was to resume playing when app goes background(using javascript), but this not works flawless because there is a 1-2 seconds stop, and its not stable. if anyone have any other solution to play youtube video, in the size that i set (not full screen), that can be played in background, please let me know .

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I have tried / read everything I could find and have not been able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by calling a javascript function within the webview that starts playing the video again 250ms after the application pauses.