# AVAudioSession pauses when closing the app

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I am making an app in Swift that takes a UIWebView and allows the audio to be playing in the background. The problem is, when I click the home button, the audio pauses but you can resume it from control center or the lock screen. How do I make it so it plays through being closed?  I have this code in my ApplicationDelegate DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
var activeError: NSError? = nil
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: &activeError)

if let actError = activeError {
    println("Error setting audio active: \(actError.code)")
}

var categoryError: NSError? = nil
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &categoryError)

if let catError = categoryError {
    println("Error setting audio category: \(catError.code
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled audio under background modes in capabilities? Also set application does not run in background bool to false in the plist.

Comment: I have enabled both of those.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background I hope it helps. Or also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783220/continue-playing-audio-from-html5-player-when-in-ios-background-mode

Comment: None of those worked :(