# AVAudioPlayer background task is not working [iOS]

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, background, avaudioplayer

I have tried everything:

-setup info.plist
    Required background modes : App plays audio;

-setup player:

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];

// allow app continue to play when the screen is locked
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                       error:nil];

UInt32 doSetProperty = 0;
AudioSessionSetProperty ( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
                         sizeof (doSetProperty),
                         &doSetProperty
                         );

// Registers the audio route change listener callback function
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (
                                 kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
                                 audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,
                                 self
                                 );

// Activates the audio session.

NSError *activationError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

[appSoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
[appSoundPlayer setVolume: 1.0];
[appSoundPlayer setDelegate: self];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

What am I forgetting? Is there something wrong?

Comment: can you email me your code. I have worked on it, and it's working properly, second thing is that have you tested it on device or just simulator. In case of simulator, it won't work.

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276096/cant-beginreceivingremotecontrolevents-in-ios/10278392#10278392. If even you don't got it, then please email me your code, I will solve it insha Allah, khalid0491@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Audio Category to Playback:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
```

If you then want to allow mixing audio with other apps, you can add this option, just make sure to do this **before** setting the audio session to active.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
```

Now you can set the audio session to active:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```