# How can I make my Radio Streaming Application keep singing when the user press the home button?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I just finished my Radio station IOS application but I have 1 problem here .. when you are listening to the streaming and press the home button the application stop working .... I did some research and found some application keep the streaming after pressing the Home Button.

is it an option in the Xcode I can enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the audio session category correctly:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

check also this question: [iPhone OS 4 Multitasking - Playing Audio In background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007527/iphone-os-4-multitasking-playing-audio-in-background?lq=1)

Comment: thanx I just fixed it from the Plist

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, I Just set an entry in the Plist

```
Required background modes : App plays audio
```